# How to refresh the CSS so the dynamically generated elements can get styled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm generating some elements dynamically with `jQuery`, but I already have the classes built in a stylesheet. (I'm modifying an app).
How can I make the classes in the dynamically generated elements work?

All I found was ways to insert style, I don't want it, I want the elements to work with my stylesheet, is there a way?

Comment: Add a className to the element when it is added the class of the style you want to apply...`element.className = "test";`.

Comment: If you are dynamically generating elements, why not generate them with the classes you need?

Comment: I'm already generating them with the classes,  but they are not working

Comment: The classes will work without any action on your part. Something else is amiss.

Comment: @Rafael then your problem is not with the styling.  If they are added to the DOM with the class associations and the classes are well-defined, the styling will show up.  You have another problem, it seems.

Comment: I'm generating them with the classes  inside the tags

Comment: @Rafael can you give us an example of what one of these generated elements look like, and how you are adding it to the DOM?

Comment: `$("#blah").append(<div class="lalala"></div>`

Comment: Tomorrow when I get to work,  I'll edit the question with a real example

Answer (score 1):

**For appending css `.class` on runtime you can use `.addclass()` function**

`$( "#element" ).addClass( "cssClassName" );`

See this for more info: http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

**For changing `css` property on runtime use the `.css()` function from `jQuery` library:**

`$( '.className' ).css( "background-color", color );`

See this for more info: http://api.jquery.com/css/